Windows Defender Firewall rules not applying to devices connected to hotspot
I have a windows 10 computer connected to my router through an ethernet connection and the hotspot enabled on my computer and have an IoT device connected through it. I created an Inbound and Outbound rule in windows defender to block all traffic from any IP address on my network to a specific remote IP address.
This rule works when i try to ping that IP address from my computer, but if i try to ping from the IoT device, it is still allowed through. Furthermore, wireshark is showing that all traffic, not just ICMP, is also allowed in and out of the device.
I have the rules set to apply to all interfaces (domain, private, public) but for some reason this device is still able to communicate freely to this IP address. is there something im missing?
more information: the in/out rules are set to apply to any program and any protocol/ports

I've not tried this myself, but to me it makes sense - in its default configuration, Windows is not designed to act as a server. So the Windows Defender firewall will be designed to sit between the IP stack and the host, and will not affect data passing only through the network stack. The data path from the device, through the hotspot, to the router never impinges on anything apart from the network stacks and so does not get blocked by the firewall.
